# QueryDSL Use Superclass Fields

Tags: hibernate, querydsl, superclass

I'm trying to use QueryDSL to make it easier to handle loading of 'Static' reference data.

Superclass:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @SuperBuilder
    public class DescriptionBase extends ModelBase {
    
        @Column(name = "NAME")
        protected String name;
    
        @Column(name = "LANG")
        protected String lang;
    
        @Column(name = "DESCR")
        protected String description;
    
    }
```

Next level superclass:

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    @Data
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    @SuperBuilder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    /**
     * This is the System Data 'Base class'
     * Not the System Database!!!!
     */
    public class SystemDataBase extends DescriptionBase {
    
        @Column(name = "SDORDER")
        private Long order;
    
    }
```

Actual reference entity to be loaded & displayed:

```
    @Entity(name = "EmpAccountType")
    @Table(name = "ACCOUNTTYPE")
    @Data
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    public class EmpAccountType extends SystemDataBase {
    
        @Column(name = "CREDITS")
        private long credits;
    
        @Column(name = "MAXANNOUNCEMENTS")
        private long maxAnnouncements;
    
    }
```

Different reference entity to be loaded & displayed:

```
    @Entity(name = "EmployerType")
    @Table(name = "EMPLOYERTYPE")
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
    public class EmployerType extends SystemDataBase {
    
        @Column(name = "DESCRS")
        private String descShort;
    
    }
```

Loading these Generically with QueryDSL is fine:

```
    public <T> List<T> loadEntitiesByCriteriaAndSdOrder(SearchCriteria sc, EntityPath<T> entityPath) {

        queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
        JPAQuery<T> query = queryFactory.
                selectFrom(entityPath);
        List<T> results = query.fetch();
        return results;
    }
```

But whenever I try to filter on the baseclass 'lang' field it throws:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'systemDataBase.lang' [select empAccountType
from com.foo.bar.model.EmpAccountType empAccountType



    public <T> List<T> loadEntitiesByCriteriaAndSdOrder(SearchCriteria sc, EntityPath<T> entityPath) {

        QSystemDataBase qSystemDataBase = QSystemDataBase.systemDataBase;       //I point to the field on the superclass
        queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
        JPAQuery<T> query = queryFactory.
                selectFrom(entityPath)
                .where(qSystemDataBase.lang.eq(sc.getLangDesc()));

        List<T> results = query.fetch();                                        //But the error is thrown from here
        return results;
    }
```

How can I alter my generic loadEntities method so that I can filter (and later sort) on a field of the superclass?

Thank you.